# How can I retrieve geoPoints from parse and store it in a tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Hi I have an app that is storing geoPoints with names in a parse server from witch I am able to retrieve the data to the console but I'm not  managing to populate the tableView with them. How could I do this ? thanks !

here is the code I use to store the data:

```
let geoPoint = PFObject(className: "location")

geoPoint["location"] = activePlace
geoPoint["spot"] = places
geoPoint.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succes, error) -> Void in
    print("place has been saved")
}
```

and here is the code I am using to retrieve it:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) in
   
    
    if error != nil {
        
        print(error)
        
    }else {
        
        print(object)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
}
```

This is how I determine my tableView:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return 1
    
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return places.count
    
    
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
  
    
    return cell
    
    
    
}
```

and this is how "places" is determined :

```
var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]
```

And here is what I have on the parse server:

[image: This in from the parse server]

Thanks for the help !

EDIT: This is what I get in the console :

```
Optional([<location: 0x7fd383e34940, objectId: K4E1Dn0qqV, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f2e070>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f30600, objectId: D4tdDJcA4x, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f14370>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f328c0, objectId: aEyiGvNmze, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f32c00>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f32f80, objectId: r9DVe2KJde, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f33320>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f336a0, objectId: 9LwM4ATHFC, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f14140>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3246293922446";
            lon = "-122.023606373578";
            name = other;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f33c00, objectId: QM8rg2NKNf, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f34040>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = place;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3313521358974";
            lon = "-122.030724242466";
            name = house;
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3246293922446";
            lon = "-122.023606373578";
            name = other;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f343c0, objectId: NjlsykJtTf, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f34690>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f34a10, objectId: qdOPtRVzew, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f34c70>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f34ff0, objectId: DC5ZW7WRNO, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f35250>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f355d0, objectId: rCZIaHlceC, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f358a0>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f35c20, objectId: 2LI1u9KyNt, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f35ef0>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f36270, objectId: YKd0q9uQcY, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f365b0>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3263892401666";
            lon = "-122.019776452882";
            name = "new one";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f36930, objectId: rGd3ChyOcV, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f36d60>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3263892401666";
            lon = "-122.019776452882";
            name = "new one";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3247014690037";
            lon = "-122.020914298787";
            name = "mc laren";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f37110, objectId: aunhPqs1Ww, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f375a0>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3263892401666";
            lon = "-122.019776452882";
            name = "new one";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3247014690037";
            lon = "-122.020914298787";
            name = "mc laren";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3246335613548";
            lon = "-122.023146659295";
            name = boom;
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383f37950, objectId: CtWCmwuZHv, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383f37c60>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        }
    );
}, <location: 0x7fd383cc37a0, objectId: AHHsEyrCJk, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fd383e228d0>";
    location = "-1";
    spot =     (
                {
            lat = 90;
            lon = 90;
            name = "GO to map to add spot";
        },
                {
            lat = "37.3306871385499";
            lon = "-122.03026490349";
            name = "20405\U201320449 Mariani Ave";
        }
    );
}])
```

EDIT 2 :This is the whole tableView code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var rideSpots = [""]

//test start

class Place {
    var ACL : String
    var location : String
    
    init(ACL : String, location : String) {
        self.ACL = ACL
        self.location = location
    }
}
let places2 : [Place] = []
//test stop

var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activePlace = -1

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func companyNameUpdatedAlert(title: String, error: String, indexPath: Int) {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        
        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
            
            textField.placeholder = "Enter new text"
            
        }
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            
            let lat = places[indexPath]["lat"]!
            
            let lon = places[indexPath]["lon"]!
            
            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath)
            
            places.insert(["name" : alert.textFields![0].text!, "lat" : lat, "lon" : lon], atIndex: indexPath)
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            
            
        }))
        
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
        let changeText = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Change spot name" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            
            self.companyNameUpdatedAlert("Update text", error: "enter text below", indexPath: indexPath.row)
            
        })
     /*
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete" , handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void in
            
            places.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(places, forKey: "places")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
 
        })
        */
        return [changeText]
        
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //retrieve the data from parse start
        
        //first start of test retrieving
        
        let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
            
            
            if error != nil {
                
                print(error)
                
            }else {
                
                
                
                print(object)
                
                for object in (objects)! {
                    
                    // Retrieve data needed and add to places (example ACL and location)
                    let ACL : String = object["ACL"] as! String
                    let location : String = object["location"] as! String
                    let place : Place = Place(ACL : ACL, location : location)
                    self.places.append(place)
                }
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }
        
        
        //end of test retrieving

    /*
        let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) in
            
            
            if error != nil {
                
                print(error)
                
            }else {
                
                print(object)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }
        }
    */
    
            //retrieve the data from parse stop
            
            
            if places.count == 1 {
                
                places.removeAtIndex(0)
                
                places.append(["name":"GO to map to add spot","lat":"90","lon":"90"])
                
                
                
                
            }
            if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") != nil {
                
                places = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("places") as! [Dictionary]
                
                
            }
            
        }
    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        
        didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        
    }
    
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return places.count
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]
      
        
        return cell
        
        
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        
        activePlace = indexPath.row
        
        return indexPath
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "newPlace" {
            
            activePlace = -1
            
            
        }
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
    tableView.reloadData()
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a cellForRowAtIndexPath method, and in what type of view did you add the tableView? UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the cellForRowAtIndexPath method also it is in a UITableViewController

Comment: if your print places before the self.tableView.reloadData() do you still get the data (?), it looks like you are not adding the queried object to the array of places? your print the data received (hence the console output) but do not update the variable used to update the tableView (places.append(...)?

Comment: I am already printing it before ? what exactly do you mean ? I'm probably not adding the query properly to the array but how should I change it so it works ?

Comment: Having your `location` column be a number and not a location is a great way to confuse whoever tries to maintain your code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an object called places instead of a dictionary after some review. That way you can create an array of objects instead of a dictionary, which is strange.

```
class Place {
    var ACL : String
    var location : String

    init(ACL : String, location : String) {
        self.ACL = ACL
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Add the

```
var places : [Place] = []
```

inside of your query instead of just printing the object and reloading the tableView. Your datasource has not changed with each reload.

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "location")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in


    if error != nil {

        print(error)

    }else {

        print(object)

        for object in objects {
            // Retrieve data needed and add to places (example ACL and location)
            let ACL : String = object["ACL"] as String
            let location : String = object["location"] as String
            let place : Place = Place(ACL : ACL, location : location)
            self.places.append(place)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode tells me : Cannot convert value of type '[PFObject]?' to expected argument type '[ String : String]'

Comment: for object in objects {
    self.places.append( object["location"] : ["spot"] )
}, or can you post the output of print(object) so I can better understand what you are working with?

Comment: I just edited the code with what I get in the console

Comment: Edited post with changes

Comment: I tried           for object in (objects)! {
                    // Retrieve data needed and add to places (example ACL and location)
                    let spot : PFGeoPoint = object ["spot"] as! PFGeoPoint
                    let ACL : String = object["ACL"] as! String
                    let location : String = object["location"] as! String
                    let place : Place = Place(ACL : ACL, location : location,spot : spot)
                    self.places.append(place)
                }
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
            }

Comment: It asked me to unwrap and one it's done it tells me use of undeclared type 'place' is and use of unresolved identifier 'object' (in the print line) I suppose I didn't understand what you were saying?

Comment: See the class created at the top of the post, excuse me i should have put it more clearly.

Comment: I created the class and I get "use of unresolved identifier 'object' and on the line that says "self.places.append(place)" I get "Value of type 'tableViewController' has no member 'places'

Comment: did you place the ' var places : [Place] = [] ' and changed the ' (object, error) in ' to ' (objects, error) in '?

The entire point of this array is to change the use of a dictionary to a class so you need to change your cellForRow and the numberOfRowsInSection to represent this as well ;) It is easy and takes about 10 seconds but is neccesary

Comment: Yes I did just that but I have "return places.count" so I don't know what I should change since it "counts" the lines ?

Comment: What do you mean with count the lines? places.count returns the amount of places objects thus the amount of rows you need in the tableView right?

Comment: The places.count displays the number places that are supposed to be in the tableView so I don't understand why they should change ? I edited the question and added the full code of my tableView maybe this will help?

Comment: change numberOfRowsInSection to return places2.count and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath set cell.textlabel.text = places2[indexPath.row].location // or whatever property you want to output to the tableviewcell

Comment: Just did that , however in print(object)
                
                for object in (objects)! {
                    
                    // Retrieve data needed and add to places (example ACL and location)
                    let ACL : String = object["ACL"] as! String
                    let location : String = object["location"] as! String
                    let places.append(place)
                }     In the first line I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'object' and on the last line I get : "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'